# Javascript variables are changing by reference - how do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, like so:

```
weekStore = [
  {week: 1, weekTimes: ["mon01", "tue01"]},
  {week: 2, weekTimes: []}
];
```

At some point, this happens:

```
weekStore[1].weekTimes = weekStore[0].weekTimes;
```

Which has the effect I want. But, if I then change it, like this:

```
weekStore[0].weekTimes = ["mon01","wed01"];
```

Then the array goes to:

```
weekStore = [
  {week: 1, weekTimes: ["mon01","wed01"]},
  {week: 2, weekTimes: ["mon01","wed01"]}
];
```

Which is a problem. How do I make it so that when I change `weekStore[1].weekTimes`, it only changes once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to copy the original array to a new array:

```
weekStore[1].weekTimes = weekStore[0].weekTimes.slice();
weekStore[1].weekTimes = [...weekStore[0].weekTimes];
weekStore[1].weekTimes = Array.from(weekStore[0].weekTimes);
weekStore[1].weekTimes = [].concat(weekStore[0].weekTimes);
weekStore[1].weekTimes = weekStore[0].weekTimes.flat(0);
```

Comment: And if I use them, when I update weekStore[0].weekTimes, it won't change weekStore[1].weekTimes?

Comment: Yes. I suppose you tried it? Since this *creates* a new array, assigning to `weekStore[1].weekTimes[0]` will not change what `weekStore[0].weekTimes[0]` has. However, if those entries are not strings (like in your example), but are objects, you may want to also make copies of those objects.

Comment: @trincot you can also use `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: Nice collection of different methods! I would like to add:  if you are dealing with a deeper structure of arrays and objects you could also use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(weekStore[0].weekTimes))`. to generate a deep copy of everything inside. This is slightly "more costly", i. e. requires more computational effort but guarantees that there are no references being shared. But you will have to take extra care of `date` objects, as these will end up as ISO string representations.

Comment: Nice! Once more way `weekStore[0].weekTimes.filter(_ => 1)`

Comment: There are of course many: `.filter(Object)`, and in this particular OP-case: `.map(String)`. Other solutions involving `reduce`, `reduceRight`, ...etc, ...etc. But I restricted myself to solutions without callbacks or type conversions. I just added `.flat(0)`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because arrays are reference types in JavaScript. That means that if you assign an array, it is the reference to the original array that is copied, not the value of the array.

To change the value of weekStore[1].weekTimes only once, you should create a new array by cloning an original array. One way to clone the array is to use the spread operator like this :  [...weekStore[0].weekTimes]

You can learn more about cloning and the spread operator here: https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/